# How to stamp archived articles?

Tags: templates

I am looking for a way to "stamp" all archived articles with a clearly visible "Archived" stamp.

I'm thinking of applying a special template for articles in the archived state, but templates are only applied based on menu-entries as far as I can see.

Do I need to fix my template so that it "inspects" the article it is showing? If so how can I do that?

Also what would be suggestions for css for an "Archived" stamp? I'm thinking semi-transparent across the content, or crossed out heading with "Archived" in red behind it.

Comment: Are you using the "com_content" component? By what method are you using to "archive" your articles--article status? Are the "archived" articles intermingled with "published" articles in your categories or are you using a separate category or menu item?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken archived articles won't show on the site alongside with published articles. Here's how I would approach this:

1. Use either a category or a tag to identify "archived" articles rather than actually archiving them.
2. Create a template override for com_content and update the code to apply a custom CSS class to your article DIV.
3. In your CSS create a rule for that new class to have a faded background image of the word "Archived" repeated and slanted 45 degrees.